# Create new column with a filter built-in on power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create columns for end of month totals for both quantity and sales fields and I need to filter on specific dates for this to occur. Currently I have been trying the below but it is not returning the desired outcome, instead it returns nothing, here is the function I tried to create:

```
      Column_name = CALCULATE(SUM(table_name[QTY]), FILTER(Date_table, 
      Date_ table[Date] = 4/30/2017))
```

FYI the date column in the date table is formatted like that MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

Power BI will not recognize a date in that format.

Try using `DATE(2017, 4, 30)` or `DATEVALUE("4/30/2017")` instead.